# Does google have access to all information on a Protonmail android app?

Tags: email-spoofing

Gmail reads my emails so Protonmail becomes more appealing to me. It is more secure, is open source and they do not read your emails or give away your information to third parties. But, Protonmail also has an android app.
 Now, if I install the app on an android device and log in, can Google steal my login credentials and spy on my E-mails from there?

Comment: Welcome to Information Security.  As a general guideline, please try to ask a specific technical question, only including relevant details, not a huge page of conspiracy theory, followed by a single line of question.

Comment: I edited the question. I added more details.

Answer (score 1):

It is not known to what extend google snoops on android customers.
I believe the Google Play Services are commonly installed with full privileges which you can find under "Device admin apps". That could allow them to snoop on you, but doesn't necessarily mean they do.
If you don't trust the Google Play Services, you could install a custom ROM without Google Play Services, (Or at least MircoG if you trust them) to mitigate the risk.